# Session cookie is causing a problem in a custom RSS feed in my theme

Tags: views, 8, theming

I use **Drupal 8.7.11**.

I personalized the RSS feed via a function in my theme `my_theme_preprocess_views_view_row_rss()` in `view.inc` file.

I added this to add `content:encoded` tag in RSS feed called **google_news**.

```
if ($variables['row']->description['#view_mode'] === 'google_news') {
    $variables['content_encoded'] = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($node->get('field_mg_paragraph')->view('google_news'));
}
```

This code adds the `content:encoded` tag to the RSS feed, but it only works with a few exceptions.

This works the first time you open the RSS feed `/feeds/google-news.xml` page (directly by URL, without going through the site).

It no longer works when I refresh the page after visiting the home page of the site or a blog post while logged in as administrator / user.

I investigated, and a **SESS cookie is placed in my browser**, obviously, this cookie is problematic.

[image]

**Anyone have any feedback on it?**

If I am disconnected and that I delete cookies, or that I navigate in private navigation on Google Chrome, I do not have this problem of cookie placed in the browser, and therefore my code works, it adds the `content:encoded` tag.

Comment: It's not the cookie causing your problem - it's more a symptom that suggests that your solution doesn't play nicely with caching. A session cookie being created is perfectly normal behaviour. It may be that the check you are making is not 100% reliable when output is cached, and you may have to use a slightly different approach.

Comment: Thanks @AlfredArmstrong ! OK, I'll try to have another approach. Obviously, when I empty the Drupal cache via the interface provided for this purpose, the addition of the `content: encoded` tag is well done, but when I refresh the page of the RSS feed, the tag disappears. It appears only once. An idea?

Comment: I have found in the past that the variables passed in to preprocess functions may vary so you probably need to see if there's a more reliable way to get that view mode